# How do I foreach Requests 2.0 callback items using json and javascript?

Tags: facebook, json

I'm a noob to JSON, and would like to do a `foreach` through all the variables that are given to the callback after a user of my Facebook application invites many users to it, using Requests 2.0

According to Facebook, this is the callback that is received.

```
{
  "request_ids": [
    0: "[request_id]",
    1: "[request_id]"
  ]
}
```

When I try to validate that with [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com), it comes up as invalid. That doesn't help me at all. I understand that the JSON is stored in a variable called `response`. [You can look that up here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#sendingrequests)

I want to do a `foreach` of all the request id's so that it'll go something like this. Damn I don't know how to do for/foreach loops in javascript.

```
for (response["*"] key in response){
    document.write("ajaxcontrols.php?createSlapAction=REQUEST_ID");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.request_ids.length; i++) {
  alert("Invitation ID: " + response.request_ids[i]);
}
```